# JMeter - converting File to String to Array

Tags: arrays, string, csv, jmeter

I need to do the following:

1. Read a .csv file into a variable. Csv file is having one single row with a string like (110,111,112,113,114)
2. Using this String variable, split the content on the basis of a comma",".

What I have done:

1. I have added a Thread Group

2a. Added a user defined variable 'Config Element'.

2b. Added a variable named 'issueIds' having value ${__FileToString(D:\TestCasesId.csv,,issueIds)}

3a. Now I added a JSR223 Sampler with the following code:

```
String lineItems1 = ${issueIds};
log.info(lineItems1);
```

3b. Executing this give the following error:

```
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``String lineItems1 = 114660,114661,114662,114663; log.info(lineItems1); ;'' Encountered "114661" at line 1, column 28.
 in inline evaluation of: ``String lineItems1 = 114660,114661,114662,114663; log.info(lineItems1); ;'' at line number 1
```

4a. Added a BeanShell Sampler with the following script:

```
String lineItems2 = ${issueIds};
String[] lineItems2Arr = lineItems2.split(",");
log.info(lineItems2);
log.info(lineItems2Arr[0]);
```

4b. Executing this give the following error:

```
Response code:500
Response message:org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``String lineItems2 = 114660,114661,114662,114663; String[] lineItems2Arr = lineIt . . . '' Encountered "114661" at line 1, column 28.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing 2 things wrong:

1. Inlining [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripting elements is not recommended, you should be using `vars` shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance instead like:

   ```
   String lineItems1 = vars.get("issueIds");
   ```
2. Since [JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) therefore consider choosing `groovy` from the language drop-down

Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell, it supports all modern Java SDK features and [provides some syntax sugar on top of it](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html), check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) article for more details.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, the following is working:

`
String lineItems1 = vars.get("issueIds");
log.info(lineItems1);
String[] myArray = lineItems1.split(',');
for (String values : myArray)
{
 log.info(values);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

In case amount of comma separated fields is the same for all used csv files, you can consider using 'CSV Data Set Config' instead of manual splitting. In that case you will have a separate variable for each column in the csv, e.g.

```
id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
110,111,112,113,114
```

Comment: Thank you Leu, but No, i do not need these as separate rows. I need to read them all as one plus as separate elements.